# Maximum number of elemets in the range of function $ f{2012} $

Tags: functions

Consider a family of functions $ f_m : N \cup \{0\} \to N \cup \{0\} $ that follows the relations :
     $ f_m(a+b) = f_m(f_m(a)) + f_m(b) $, 
 $ f_m(km) = 0 $

HERE m is any positive integer apart from 1. How can I find the maximum number of elements in the range of function $ f_{2012} $ ?

Comment: What is the set of $k$ values? Is it $k=1,2,...$ so that one has $f(m)=f(2m)=f(3m)=...=0$? [Can't see why restrict $m$ not to be 1 since the question only asks about when $m=2012.$]

Comment: Yes the values of K is 1,2,3,4.....

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it this is trivial, so you may have an error in the question.

If the sum of two non-negative numbers is zero then both must be zero. But

$$0 = f_{2012}(k\,2012) = f_{2012}(k\,2011 +k) = f_{2012}(f_{2012}(k\,2011))+f_{2012}(k)$$ so both $f_{2012}(f_{2012}(k\,2011))$ and $f_{2012}(k)$ must be zero for all $k$.

Comment: I wonder what happens if one only requires the map to be into $\mathbb{Z}$.